# How do I drop any constraint only if it exists in sybase?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, dd, isql

I can drop a table, procedure, views if it exists using the following code but do not know how to do the same with a constraints(foreign key, check constraint):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE user = 'owner' and name = 'tablename' AND type = 'U')DROP TABLE owner.tablename 
go
```

I have tried with following code -

```
  - alter table dbname.owner.tablename drop constraint Fk_name FOREIGN
        KEY (References-colname)

  - if exists (select 1 from syscolumns
                where id = object_id("some_table")
                    and name = "some_column")
                begin
                    alter table some_table drop some_column
                end 


  - IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE user = 'owner' and name = 'FK_name' AND type = 'RI')
ALTER TABLE owner.tablename DROP CONSTRAINT [owner.Fk_name]
GO
```

Here is my DDL generated from ddlgen command -

```
DROP TABLE fin_code2 
go 
DROP TABLE Student1 
go 
DROP TABLE SalesOrders 
go 
DROP TABLE DEPT 
go 
DROP TABLE library_books 
go 
DROP TABLE brand 
go 
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE 
go 
DROP TABLE DEPT_test 
go 
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE 
go 
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE24 
go 
DROP TRIGGER reminder 
go 
DROP VIEW sysquerymetrics 
go 
DROP VIEW emp_dept 
go 
DROP VIEW empview 
go 
DROP PROCEDURE showdept 
go 
USE master
go


PRINT "<<<< CREATE DATABASE geetextract>>>>"
go


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
       WHERE name = 'geetextract')
    DROP DATABASE geetextract
go


IF (@@error != 0)
BEGIN
    PRINT "Error dropping database 'geetextract'"
    SELECT syb_quit()
END
go


CREATE DATABASE geetextract
        ON master = '6M' -- 1536 pages
    WITH DURABILITY = FULL
       , DML_LOGGING = FULL
go


ALTER DATABASE geetextract
        ON master = '10240M' -- 2621440 pages
go


use geetextract
go

exec sp_changedbowner 'sa', true 
go

exec master.dbo.sp_dboption geetextract, 'ddl in tran', true
go

checkpoint
go


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for User 'geetanjali'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print '<<<<< CREATING User - "geetanjali" >>>>>'
go 

exec sp_adduser 'geetanjali' ,'geetanjali' ,'public'
go 


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.geetanjali.DEPT'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.geetanjali.DEPT" >>>>>'
go

use geetextract
go 

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

create table DEPT (
    DeptNo                          int                              not null,
    DeptName                        varchar(20)                      not null,
    Mgr                             int                              not null,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( DeptNo )  on 'default' 
)
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 


setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Index 'DeptNoind'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print '<<<<< CREATING Index - "DeptNoind" >>>>>'
go 

create nonclustered index DeptNoind 
on geetextract.geetanjali.DEPT(DeptNo)
go 


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.dbo.DEPT_test'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.dbo.DEPT_test" >>>>>'
go

setuser 'dbo'
go 

create table DEPT_test (
    DeptNo                          int                              not null,
    DeptName                        varchar(20)                      not null,
    Mgr                             int                              not null 
)
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 


setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.geetanjali.EMPLOYEE'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.geetanjali.EMPLOYEE" >>>>>'
go

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

set quoted_identifier on
go 

create table EMPLOYEE (
    EmpNo                           int                              not null,
    DeptNo                          int                              not null,
    LastName                        varchar(20)                      not null,
    FirstName                       varchar(20)                      not null,
    Salary                          int                              not null,
    Description                     text                                 null,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( EmpNo )  on 'default',
CONSTRAINT valid_check CHECK     (Salary > 10000))
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 

sp_placeobject 'default', 'geetanjali.EMPLOYEE.tEMPLOYEE'
go 


setuser
go 
set quoted_identifier off
go 


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Trigger 'geetextract.geetanjali.reminder'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print '<<<<< CREATING Trigger - "geetextract.geetanjali.reminder" >>>>>'
go 

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

create trigger geetanjali.reminder on geetanjali.EMPLOYEE for insert, update as print "Don't forget to print a report for accounting."
go 

setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.dbo.EMPLOYEE'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.dbo.EMPLOYEE" >>>>>'
go

setuser 'dbo'
go 

create table EMPLOYEE (
    EmpNo                           int                              not null,
    DeptNo                          int                              not null,
    LastName                        varchar(20)                      not null,
    FirstName                       varchar(20)                      not null,
    Salary                          int                              not null,
    Description                     text                                 null,
CONSTRAINT valid_check CHECK      (Salary > 10000))
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 

sp_placeobject 'default', 'dbo.EMPLOYEE.tEMPLOYEE'
go 


setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.dbo.EMPLOYEE24'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.dbo.EMPLOYEE24" >>>>>'
go

setuser 'dbo'
go 

create table EMPLOYEE24 (
    EmpNo                           int                              not null,
    DeptNo                          int                              not null,
    LastName                        varchar(20)                      not null,
    FirstName                       varchar(20)                      not null,
    Salary                          int                              not null,
    Description                     text                                 null,
CONSTRAINT valid_check23 CHECK      (Salary > 10000))
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 

sp_placeobject 'default', 'dbo.EMPLOYEE24.tEMPLOYEE24'
go 


setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.geetanjali.SalesOrders'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.geetanjali.SalesOrders" >>>>>'
go

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

create table SalesOrders (
    FinancialCode                   char(2)                          not null,
    CustomerID                      int                              not null,
    History                         char(100)                        not null,
    OrderDate                       date                             not null,
    ID                              bigint                           not null,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( ID )  on 'default' 
)
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 


setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.geetanjali.Student1'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.geetanjali.Student1" >>>>>'
go

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

set quoted_identifier on
go 

create table Student1 (
    StudentId                       int                              not null,
    Name                            char(100)                        not null,
    Class                           char(50)                         not null,
    School                          char(100)                        not null,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( StudentId )  on 'default',
 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( StudentId, Name )  on 'default',
CONSTRAINT test_const CHECK     (StudentId > 0))
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 


setuser
go 
set quoted_identifier off
go 


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.geetanjali.brand'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.geetanjali.brand" >>>>>'
go

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

set quoted_identifier on
go 

create table brand (
    code                            char(8)                          not null,
    valid                           int                              not null,
    rowid                           numeric(10,0)                    not null,
        CONSTRAINT brand_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( code )  on 'default',
        CONSTRAINT brand_is_valid UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( code, valid )  on 'default',
CONSTRAINT valid_check1 CHECK     (valid IN (0,1)))
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 


setuser
go 
set quoted_identifier off
go 


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.geetanjali.fin_code2'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.geetanjali.fin_code2" >>>>>'
go

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

create table fin_code2 (
    code                            int                              not null,
    type                            char(10)                         not null,
    description                     char(235)                        not null,
    id                              bigint                           not null,
 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ( code )  on 'default' 
)
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 


setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Table 'geetextract.geetanjali.library_books'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
print '<<<<< CREATING Table - "geetextract.geetanjali.library_books" >>>>>'
go

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

create table library_books (
    isbn                            char(20)                         not null,
    copyright_date                  date                             not null,
    title                           char(100)                        not null,
    author                          char(50)                         not null,
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( isbn )  on 'default' 
)
lock allpages
with dml_logging = full
 on 'default'
go 


setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Index 'au_id_ind'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print '<<<<< CREATING Index - "au_id_ind" >>>>>'
go 

create nonclustered index au_id_ind 
on geetextract.geetanjali.library_books(isbn)
go 


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for View 'geetextract.geetanjali.emp_dept'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print '<<<<< CREATING View - "geetextract.geetanjali.emp_dept" >>>>>'
go 

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

set quoted_identifier on
go 

create view emp_dept AS SELECT EmpNo, DEPT.DeptNo FROM EMPLOYEE JOIN DEPT ON EMPLOYEE.DeptNo = DEPT.DeptNo
go 

set quoted_identifier off
go 

setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for View 'geetextract.geetanjali.empview'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print '<<<<< CREATING View - "geetextract.geetanjali.empview" >>>>>'
go 

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

set quoted_identifier on
go 

create view empview (FirstName) as select distinct FirstName from EMPLOYEE
go 

set quoted_identifier off
go 

setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Stored Procedure 'geetextract.geetanjali.showdept'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print '<<<<< CREATING Stored Procedure - "geetextract.geetanjali.showdept" >>>>>'
go 

setuser 'geetanjali'
go 

set quoted_identifier on
go 

CREATE PROCEDURE showdept @deptname varchar(30) AS SELECT EMPLOYEE.EmpNo FROM EMPLOYEE, DEPT WHERE DEPT.DeptNo = EMPLOYEE.DeptNo
go 


sp_procxmode 'showdept', unchained
go 

set quoted_identifier off
go 

setuser
go 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Dependent DDL for Object(s)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
use geetextract
go 

sp_addthreshold geetextract, 'logsegment', 24, sp_thresholdaction
go 

Grant Select on dbo.sysobjects(name,id,uid,type,userstat,sysstat,indexdel,schemacnt,sysstat2,crdate,expdate,deltrig,instrig,updtrig,seltrig,ckfirst,cache,objspare,versionts,loginame,identburnmax,spacestate,erlchgts,sysstat3) to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysindexes to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.syscolumns to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.systypes to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysprocedures to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.syscomments to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.syssegments to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.syslogs to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysprotects to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysusers to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysalternates to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysdepends to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.syskeys to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysusermessages to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysreferences to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysconstraints to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.systhresholds to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysroles to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysattributes to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysslices to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.systabstats to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysstatistics to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysxtypes to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysjars to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.sysqueryplans to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.syspartitions to public
go
Grant Select on dbo.syspartitionkeys to public
go
alter table geetextract.geetanjali.EMPLOYEE
add constraint EMPLOYEE_DeptNo_896003192 FOREIGN KEY (DeptNo) REFERENCES geetextract.geetanjali.DEPT(DeptNo)
go

alter table geetextract.geetanjali.fin_code2
add constraint fin_code2_id_800002850 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES geetextract.geetanjali.SalesOrders(ID)
go

alter table geetextract.geetanjali.EMPLOYEE drop constraint EMPLOYEE_DeptNo_896003192 FOREIGN KEY (DeptNo)  
go 
alter table geetextract.geetanjali.fin_code2 drop constraint fin_code2_id_800002850 FOREIGN KEY (id)  
go 
alter table geetextract.geetanjali.EMPLOYEE add CONSTRAINT valid_check CHECK     (Salary > 10000) 
go 
alter table geetextract.geetanjali.EMPLOYEE drop constraint valid_check 
go 
alter table geetextract.geetanjali.Student1 add CONSTRAINT test_const CHECK     (StudentId > 0) 
go 
alter table geetextract.geetanjali.Student1 drop constraint test_const 
go 
alter table geetextract.geetanjali.brand add CONSTRAINT valid_check1 CHECK     (valid IN (0,1)) 
go 
alter table geetextract.geetanjali.brand drop constraint valid_check1 
go 
alter table geetanjali.EMPLOYEE  DISABLE TRIGGER geetanjali.reminder 
go 
alter table geetanjali.EMPLOYEE  ENABLE TRIGGER geetanjali.reminder 
go
```

- it will execute but not dropping that key.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the "if exists" check on sysconstraints, following your example

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysconstraints WHERE constrid=object_id('EMPLOYEE_FK') and tableid=object_id('test')) ALTER TABLE test.EMPLOYEE DROP CONSTRAINT [test.EMPLOYEE_FK]

GO

Of course you may also join sysobjects and sysconstraints in order to chck the owner of the object.
Concerning the foreign keys you may also use sysreferences

I refined this answer after comments.

Comment: I have tried above solution as - but its not working if i tried
I have execute query - SELECT * FROM sysconstraints WHERE constrid=object_id('test.EMPLOYEE_FK') - it will return one row but if I remove test from this query then result will be 0.Then I will execute - IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysconstraints WHERE constrid=object_id('test.EMPLOYEE_FK')) ALTER TABLE test.EMPLOYEE DROP CONSTRAINT [test.EMPLOYEE_FK] GO - it will prompt an error - cannot drop the constraints because it doesn't exists in system catalogues. So can you please suggest how can I execute with specific owner.

Comment: You are correct, try this  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysconstraints WHERE constrid=object_id('test.EMPLOYEE_FK') and tableid=object_id('test')) ALTER TABLE test.EMPLOYEE DROP CONSTRAINT [test.EMPLOYEE_FK] GO      You need to check both table name and constraint name

Comment: This also not working, I have also checked only this query to get output SELECT * FROM sysconstraints WHERE constrid=object_id('test.EMPLOYEE_FK') and tableid=object_id('test') but there is no result. Also above query but it will not drop any fk if there is no rows from select clause.

Comment: please send specific DDL for the tables and the constraints. The query I sent works in my environment, maybe I am missing something

Comment: this  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysconstraints WHERE object_name(constrid)='fin_code2_id_800002850' and tableid=object_id('fin_code2')) 
ALTER TABLE dbo.fin_code2 DROP CONSTRAINT [fin_code2_id_800002850]     will drop  the constraint, can you verify?

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the sysconstraints table to determine if a constraint exists.

Comment: its not working I have tried with syscolumns instead of sysobjects.